# Node.js child process spawn issues with buffering?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For a project of mine I essentially want to be able to pass a command to a Node.js script and have it execute it and record the output line by line. This is what I have right now:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var child_spawn = child_process.spawn('ruby', ['test.rb']);

child_spawn.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('stdout: ' + data);

});
```

Now when I tail -f the system log this works as I would except but when I test it with a trivial ruby script I wrote it recieves all the output at once as if it were buffered?

The script in question is:

```
puts "hello"
sleep(1)
puts "there"
sleep(1)
puts "my"
sleep(1)
puts "name"
sleep(1)
puts "is"
sleep(1)
puts "james"
```

When I run this on it's own it works as I'm sure you can imagine, printing out one line at a time with a second gap in between.

On the node docs (http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) I saw this:

> (Note that some programs use line-buffered I/O internally. That doesn't affect node.js but it means data you send to the child process is not immediately consumed.)

Is that what is happening here and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vkurchatkin's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20978696/483271) answer correctly explains the reason for why this happening.

How I actually got around this however was by making use of this https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/ (available on npm), it allows emulation of a terminal so Ruby doesn't buffer it's output and seems to have a compatible API to child_process from what I've seen so far.

Comment: https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/ is not able to use now, using this https://github.com/Microsoft/node-pty

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what happens. Check this:

```
puts "hello"
STDOUT.flush
sleep(1)
puts "there"
STDOUT.flush
sleep(1)
puts "my"
STDOUT.flush
sleep(1)
puts "name"
STDOUT.flush
sleep(1)
puts "is"
STDOUT.flush
sleep(1)
puts "james"
STDOUT.flush
```

I assume that ruby detects if stout is not a tty, and if so buffers all the output and flushes when the script exits. Putting `STDOUT.sync = true` seems to fix this issue.

Comment: Ah interesting, that does technically fix it. The problem is in my case I'm not always going to have control over the script/command so I can't make adjustments like that. I actually managed to get this to work in Ruby using something like this https://gist.github.com/jamesrwhite/3369fa6c04a6e14fb3a8 and the test.rb script will work as expected without the flushes after each print.